Establish Websocket connection by client IP address
How can my Websocket server initiate a connection to a client choosing it by its IP address?
I have multiple clients each one having static IP.
The list of expected IPs is stored on the Server side.
I would expect something like (demo code):
const webSocket = require('ws');
const ip = "111.111.111.111";
const ws = new webSocket(ip);
ws.on('open', () => {
    console.log(`Connected to client at ${ip}`);
});


The client connects to the server, not the other way around. Otherwise you'll need to run some sort of server on those "clients".

Alejandro, as far as I understood, Websocket protocol comes to enable connections in both directions, unlike HTTP, this is why I try to use it in my project

No, websockets enable two-way communications in real time, not connections. To establish the connection itself you still have to have a server listening, and a browser is not such thing.

I see. Thank you for clarifying this to me. So can it be an acceptable practice to make an edge device act both as a client and as a server?

I would just make the clients connect to the server as soon as they're ready to use, and the server maintain a list of connected clients, to which it can talk to any of them as long as they remain connected. The connection is initiated by the clients, but the server chooses when to send messages.

Sounds a good idea to try out. Thank you Alejandro
